# How to prove this property of limit of sequences

Tags: analysis

I read a property about limit of sequences as:

> suppose $ a_{n} \leq b_{n}, \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty }  a_{n}=a,
> \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty }  b_{n}=b $, then $a \leq b$.

I know a proof by contradiction and I am wondering how to prove this property directly? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose $\epsilon > 0$, then there is $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
b_n < b+\epsilon \quad\forall n\geq N_0
$$
and $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
a-\epsilon < a_n \quad\forall n\geq N_1
$$
So for $n= \max\{N_0, N_1\}$, one has
$$
a-\epsilon < a_n \leq b_n < b+\epsilon
$$
and so
$$
a < b+2\epsilon \quad\forall \epsilon > 0
$$
and so $a\leq b$.

However, this last statement is usually proved using contradiction, so I'm not really sure if this satisfies your (rather stringent) conditions.

Comment: thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help and it does inspire me a lot! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$b-a=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n-\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n-a_n)\geq\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0$$

Comment: This has been flagged as "low quality". Why? This is a great answer.

Comment: @AhaanRungta Auto-flagged by the system, no text, just a formula, that makes it suspicious. But sometimes answers which meet these criteria are okay or even good, that's why the system puts it in the queue, so that _people_ look at it.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @AhaanRungta Hmm.. Why not help upvote since it's not disappointing.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang My voting was locked at the time. Done now.

Comment: @AhaanRungta Oh, thanks. Even I didn't know my post was locked. The system should have at least a signal for that.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang No, your post wasn't locked, my voting for the day was locked because I used the daily maximum of 40 votes.

Comment: @AhaanRungta Well, but I still didn't know it was flagged.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang See DanielFischer's response above.

Comment: @AhaanRungta I did but I think there shall be a reminder whenever people (or machine) do something to you.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang Wait, what? Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @AhaanRungta I mean the system should tell me immediately after flagging me. But obviously not.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang I have a question on the last inequality. Do we get this inequality from the fact that $ 0\leq b_{n}-a_{n}$ and then $\lim 0 \leq  \lim (b_{n}-a_{n})$? but is this property just what we want to prove?

Comment: @MartinTien Don't think like that. Apply monotonic property, $0\leq b_n-a_n$ implies $0\leq\liminf(b_n-a_n)\leq\lim(b_n-a_n)$